# I tried installing elasticsearch helpers through pip install and got the following error.What are the prerequisites?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement helpers (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for helpers

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility
The library is compatible with all Elasticsearch versions since 0.90.x but you have to use a matching major version:

For Elasticsearch 6.0 and later, use the major version 6 (6.x.y) of the library.

For Elasticsearch 5.0 and later, use the major version 5 (5.x.y) of the library.

For Elasticsearch 2.0 and later, use the major version 2 (2.x.y) of the library, and so on

For more info. please check

https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch/